# Where are fivestar data stored?

Tags: rating

On a D7 site using [fivestar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar) , I'd like to extract data from the module but there is not such table or node in the database and looking at the source code, I could not figure out in which table/fields the fivestart data are related/stored.

So appreciate your help about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table does not have 'fivestar' in the name - try looking for the content type, or the word 'vote', or the axis name, in table names.  For example, I have a (test) content type named 'Review' with three voting axes.  The Fivestar fields are as follows:

- field_data_field_review_votes_average
- field_data_field_review_vote_axis_one
- field_data_field_review_vote_axis_three
- field_data_field_review_vote_axis_two

Answer (score 2):

Fivestar module defines a field.
Add a field to a content type. If fx you add a field named "test" of type fivestar reting to a content type then you can find the table with the name "field_data_field_test".

Comment: There is no table with this name: `field_data_field_fivestar` or any name containing `fivestar`.